# Trying to get total appointments per state. getting error in MySQL 1055

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Here is my query where I am trying to fetch appointment data by statewise

`select address.state , patient.pt_id , appointment.apt_id  from address inner join patient on address.address_id = patient.address_id inner join appointment on appointment.pt_id = patient.pt_id group by address.state;`

Is the statement I am trying to run to see if I can pull a list of appointments. If I take off the group by section the database will return a table that has all mentions of state, pt_id, and apt_id, but I need to group them by state and count how many appointments there are per state. With trying to group by state I get the following error of

> "Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'U07uXB.patient.pt_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    address.state stateName,count(1)
from
    address
inner join patient on
    address.address_id = patient.address_id
inner join appointment on
    appointment.pt_id = patient.pt_id
group by
    stateName;
```